# Refer a single post in tumblr

Tags: tumblr

I'm making a page to publish my songs and wonder if and how can I refer to a single audio post instead of all of them ( as I would using {block:Posts} ), that way I could upload and access my audio files in tumblr with more freedom to customize the entries.

Can I refer to a single post in tumblr? If yes, how?

I've seen the {PostID} "property" in their help page, but how do I get the ID from the post in the first place? and how do I select the post with that id?

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to do something like this?

```
{block:Posts}
    {postID:314159}
        …content of post with id equal to 314159…
    {/postID:314159}
{/block:Posts}
```

If you do — It is impossible to do with current Tumblr template engine

Comment: Is it possible to get all posts one by one by not using the {block:Posts} markdown?

Comment: @jeraldo nope, as far as i remember (because of pagination). So you should use API to get all the blocks

Answer (score 0):

Your best option is to either list links to the post into a separate page (which Tumblr will let you create) or some compilation post that you link to.

Your other option is to make sure your audio post share a common tag that you can refer to (http://yourtumblr.tumblr.com/tagged/mysongs). There may be advanced ajax-style techniques that will allow editing the theme itself to display only audio posts, but I don't know if or how.

Comment: Not realy what I ment. I'm talking about how the {block:Post} works like a loop getting all posts, I want to target a single specifc post.

Comment: And although I didn't say it, you can't. You can barely target a subset of posts using the templating systems (again, baring that more advanced API coding will let it happen, but I don't know how to), so single posts are right out.